# Converting timestamps into a decimal in minutes

Tags: date-and-time

I am importing a list of timestamps (hour:minutes:seconds) from a series of text files. I have the list:

```
{"12:41:43", "15:35:40", "18:28:38", "21:21:40", "0:14:51", 
"3:07:51", "6:00:43", "8:52:17", "11:43:53", "14:35:26", "17:25:18", "20:15:13"}
```

I need to figure out how to get this format into a single decimal value in minutes. In excel, this can be done simply by changing the "time" format to "number". I've explored a few options related to Date[] and other functions, but nothing seems to do what I need it to do. If there's no easy way, I imagine I could break up the sections, convert each to minutes, and add them, but such a feat is currently beyond my mathematica expertise.

If anyone is wondering, the goal is to have a single mathematica spreadsheet in which we can import the raw data file from a testing apparatus, extract the values (a certain parameter vs time) and then plot them. I'm good on the parameter, I'm just stuck getting time!

Comment: Does this give what you need: `times={"12:41:43", "15:35:40", "18:28:38", "21:21:40", "0:14:51", 
"3:07:51", "6:00:43", "8:52:17", "11:43:53", "14:35:26", "17:25:18", "20:15:13"}; minutes=(AbsoluteTime/@times -AbsoluteTime[{2015,1,1}])/60.`?

Answer (score 4):

You can get the value in number of minutes since midnight.  I not certain if this is the same as formatting a time to decimal in Excel.

You have a time format as a string so can `StringSplit` these into their components and convert them to from strings to integers with `FromDigits`.  This will give a matrix of vectors with `{hour, minute, second}` entries.  These convert to minutes by applying the following factors respectively `{60, 1, 1/60}`. Using the `Dot` product we can apply these factors to each row and sum the row. The `N` function ensures we get numerical values instead of fractions (a by product of the `1/60`).

```
timestamps = {"12:41:43", "15:35:40", "18:28:38", "21:21:40", 
  "0:14:51", "3:07:51", "6:00:43", "8:52:17", "11:43:53", "14:35:26", 
  "17:25:18", "20:15:13"}

(FromDigits /@ StringSplit[#, ":"] & /@ timestamps).{60, 1, 1/60}  // N

(* {761.717, 935.667, 1108.63, 1281.67, 14.85, 187.85, 360.717, 532.283, \
703.883, 875.433, 1045.3, 1215.22} *)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

```
{60., 1, 1/60}.DateList[#][[4 ;;]] & /@ {"12:41:43", "15:35:40", 
  "18:28:38", "21:21:40", "0:14:51", "3:07:51", "6:00:43", "8:52:17", 
  "11:43:53", "14:35:26", "17:25:18", "20:15:13"}
```

yields:

```
(* {761.717, 935.667, 1108.63, 1281.67, 14.85, 187.85, 360.717, 532.283, \
703.883, 875.433, 1045.3, 1215.22} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
times={"12:41:43", "15:35:40", "18:28:38", "21:21:40", "0:14:51", "3:07:51", 
       "6:00:43", "8:52:17", "11:43:53", "14:35:26", "17:25:18", "20:15:13"}; 

time0 = "00:00:00";
minutes = QuantityMagnitude @ DateDifference[time0, #, "Minute"]& /@ times
```

> {761.717, 935.667, 1108.63, 1281.67, 14.85, 187.85, 360.717,
>     532.283, 703.883, 875.433, 1045.3, 1215.22}

Alternatively, you can use `AbsoluteTime` to get the same result:

```
minutes = (AbsoluteTime /@ times - AbsoluteTime @ time0) / 60.
```