# How to LinearModelFit data like {{year,month,day,hour,minute,second,variable}}?

Tags: fitting, date-and-time

As the title says...I have my data in the form :

> {{year,month,day,hour,minute,second,variable},{year,month,day,hour2,minute2,second2,variable},
>   ...}

`LinearModelFit[data,x,x]` does not work :P (I am new to Mathematica, so 
any pointers will be appreciated)

Thanks

Comment: For `LinearModelFit[data,x,x]` the `data` should be `{{time, variable},{time2, variable2},...}` so you need to manipulate `data` initially

Comment: If not going for [`TimeSeriesModelFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeriesModelFit.html?q=TimeSeriesModelFit) in this case, I would use [`AbsoluteTime[{y,m,d,h,m,s}]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsoluteTime.html?q=AbsoluteTime) to convert the times. You may then use [`Standardize[ {absTime1, absTime2, ...}, First, 1&]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Standardize.html) to shift the times to start with 0.

Comment: `LinearModelFit[data,x,x]` won't work because the number of columns in _data_ is greater than the number of regressors (x). If you want to make this work, then you should use something like `lmf=LinearModelFit[data, {x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6}, {x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6}]`. Also note how your regression will contain a constant term. If you don't want that, you should include the option `_IncludeConstantBasis_->False`

Comment: @user42582 It will work because the values encoding time can be compared to representing a number by its digits. In the end it simply is a single value.

Comment: @gwr: the question presents a design matrix with 6 independent vars. `LinearModelFit[data,x,x]` will report an error when evaluated. Note, that the input data are _already_ date/time components. The fact that you interpret the question as a request for providing - in addition to making the _given_ code work - a way to _acquire_ a date/time time-stamp is something that _is not_ asked. As a side note, in my previous comment I said that the `LinearModelFit[data,x,x]` wouldn't work, not that _your_ version wouldn't work. The fact is that using `AbsoluteTime[]`is not relevant in the present context

Comment: @user42582 Well, I am assuming that one of the tenets of linear regression usually is, that the predictors should be independent from each other (avoid multicollinearity). Being modular numbers imo makes hours, minutes, seconds not independent from each other. To me `AbsoluteTime` appears to be very relevant in the context of linear models using time as a predictor.

Comment: @gwr: multicollinearity is a sample problem-the poster has not made the sample available-the question was about an incorrect mathematica function call, not about regression theory

Answer (score 1):

Comments are right. I have to convert time to seconds. 
What I did was to use the code provided by @kglr in this question [Converting timestamps into a decimal in minutes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83285/converting-timestamps-into-a-decimal-in-minutes)

Thanks to EE!